# ORACLE Insert values with select statement in same table

Tags: oracle

I have one table which gives access to certain webpages for a specific role. Lets say Local admin (profile_id=2) has access to 45 webpages. I have another role which is Local power user (profile_id=3). That user needs to have the same access as the Local admin + one more page. Since in all 25 DBs local admin has different access I want to make an insert using select statement and copy the access from profile_id=2 to profile_id=3.

These are the columns:

```
column_name data_type      nullable
PROFILE_ID  NUMBER(10,0)    No
PAGE_ID     NUMBER(10,0)    No
IS_READONLY NUMBER(1,0)     No
```

These are the constraints:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't fully understand the question but to use a table rows as a model for inserting, you just form a select that represents the rows you want to insert, with some changes:

```
--want to add every fire fighter as having another job as police officer

INSERT INTO Person(Name, Job, Salary)
SELECT CONCAT('Officer ', Name), 'Police Officer', Salary
FROM Person
WHERE Job = 'Firefighter'
```

If you want to add some new row too, union it on:

```
INSERT INTO Person(Name, Job, Salary)
SELECT CONCAT('Officer ', Name), 'Police Officer', Salary
FROM Person
WHERE Job = 'Firefighter'
UNION 
SELECT 'Officer Dredd', 'Judge', 999999 FROM dual
```

So you're selecting FROM table T with profile_id = 2, making sure that `3` is selected as the value output instead of profile_id (like I did with Job) and modifying any other fields in whatever way

Basically "write the SELECT statement that represents the rows you want, then put `INSERT INTO ...` at the top of it"

Comment: I need to have the same values as these below but to change the profile_id based on 
`select id from web_userprofiles where description='LocalPowerUser';`
`Profile_id Page_id Is_readony
  341 1090 0
  341 1240 0
  341 1380 0
  341 1410 0
  341 1510 0
  341 1520 0
  341 1540 0
  341 1550 0
`

Comment: If you want to change values based on row data, use a CASE WHEN or similar.. like `INSERT INTO X(Job) SELECT CASE WHEN Salary > 50000 THEN 'Police Sargeant' ELSE 'Police Officer' END as Job FROM X` - it changes the inserted Job to be Officer or Sargeant depending on the salary